# SMTP error 451 Temporary local - please try later

Tags: php, email, smtp, vestacp

when I try to send a mail from webmail service then I got {SMTP error 451 Temporary local - please try later } this warning! this is the screenshot-> [image: Text] . I have used vestacp and there I have config the DNS, MAIL services and all of things. does anyone know where is the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There was a problem in DNS and vestacp panel so i reconfigured the OS in **vestacp** after that it's working perfectly.**

Comment: Can you offer more details on what the problems in DNS and vestacp were?

Comment: I put the Wrong DNS server name under the vestacp panel. @Jeremy